# WebView won't focus on input field

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard, android-constraintlayout

I have an activity, containing WebView and an ImageView in a ConstraintLayout. ImageView is in parent's bottom-right and WebView is in top-left. Besides, WebView's bottom is connected to ImageView's top.

When an input field is tapped on the website, which is loaded in the WebView, I can see that activity is resized (as put on the manifest, style and code), because the ImageView is moved and is on top of the keyboard. WebView, however, doesn't change. At all. Input field stay under the keyboard UI. Frustration is killing me. I'm trying to solve this for 3rd day straight. Please help me.

PS I have also tried to detect when keyboard is opened and closed and tried to resize the WebView, but either I did it wrong, or method won't work in my case. I've done it by subscribing to the onGlobalLayout, then calculating the screen height vs window height and if their proportions meet certain requirements I'd assume that keyboard is opened. This worked flawless. Problem was updating WebView's height. I have tried to update height to the difference between screen height and keyboard height. Didn't help.

`activity_webview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="au.com.strataplus.stratamanagement.WebViewActivity">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_settings"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_settings"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="onSettingsButtonClicked"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:riv_border_color="#333333"
            app:riv_border_width="0dip"
            app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
            app:riv_mutate_background="true" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_webview_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

`WebViewActivity.java`

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_web_view);
        binding.webviewContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                binding.progressWebviewContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                binding.progressWebviewContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (Utils.endsWith(url, documentSuffixes)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PDFViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_DOCUMENT_URL, url);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        WebSettings settings = binding.webviewContent.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

        binding.webviewContent.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

`styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

As clearly NOT seen in the screenshot below, input field named `password` is under the keyboard. Settings button, the ImageView I was talking about, is right above the keyboard. Where it belongs.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you post the screenshot >

Comment: have you tried android:isScrollContainer="false" in webView?

Comment: just tried. same output. thanks for the suggestion though :)